# Comparing Winform Button Colors

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, button

I have got four buttons in my form among four three buttons (btn2 btn3 btn4) have same color.

when btn1 is clicked it will check if btn2 btn3 and btn4 are of same color without explicitly stating what color to compare. but my condition does not seem to be right
should i state this

the code I'm using is:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btn2.BackColor.Equals((btn3.BackColor) && (btn4.BackColor)))
       {
         MessageBox.Show("ALL BUTTONS ARE OF SAME COLOR");
       } 
}
```

Comment: you are testing logical and for btn3 and btn4 [they probably are being implicitly converted to 32bit ints] and then testing the result of that for equality with btn2, I can't see that working. If you really wanted to do this test btn2 against 3 and then btn2 again against btn 4. I would say though in my team we have a rule, don't use the UI as the model.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code to compare colors:

```
        if (btn2.BackColor == btn3.BackColor && btn3.BackColor == btn4.BackColor)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ALL BUTTONS ARE THE SAME COLOR");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ALL BUTTONS ARE NOT THE SAME COLOR");
        }
```